# Given two marginal distributions are they consistent with an underlying joint distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given two random probability distributions how can we check if they are consistent with an underlying joint  probability distribution?

Specifically, take two random variables $X$ and $Y$. If they are the marginals of some underlying distribution then they should satisfy the following equations,
$$ Pr(X = x_i) =  \sum_j Pr(X= x_i, Y = y_j) =  \sum_j Pr(X = x_i | Y = y_j)~ Pr(Y = y_j)$$

$$ Pr(Y = y_j) =  \sum_i Pr(X= x_i, Y = y_j) =  \sum_i Pr(Y = y_j | X = x_i) ~Pr(X = x_i)$$

Under what conditions will the above equations be satisfied?

Answer (score 2):

Any two distributions can be the marginals of a joint distribution. Simply choose the joint distribution such that the marginals are independent.